# copy and store to clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I would to copy my text from excel and store to clipboard by using AHK.

This is my code:

```
Xl.Range("A1").Copy
Xl.Range("A2").Copy
Xl.Range("A3").Copy
Xl.Range("A4").Copy
```

How to store A1-A4 to clipboard? Then I can paste back the clipboard manually.

Comment: You're only selecting one cell at at time. you need to use "A1:A4"

Comment: Why do you want to involve the clipboard? IF all you want to do is to move these data around there are other ways.

Comment: please more information about the context of this question

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range
Set wsSource = ActiveSheet 'or whatever
Set wsDest = wsSource ' or whatever
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A1:A4")
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("C1")
rngSource.Copy rngDest
```

Unless you actually want it to be on the clipboard for the user to user paste wherever they may choose then you change th elast line to `rngSource.Copy`

Comment: +1 looks ok - although not easy answering such a vague question